# can't stop action in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an action on a `CCMenu` , which is a child of a `CCLayer`-that he is a child of a `scroller`. (a scroll layer class of cocos2d)

There is an action running on this `CCMenu`,its has a name and a tag.

I just cant stop it. when i am trying to get to it, I see null value.
I have tried:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene getChildByTag:600] stopAction:repeat];
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene getChildByTag:600]getChildByTag:800 ]stopAction:repeat];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene getChildByTag:600] stopAllActions];

[self stopAllActions];
```

NOTHING .
Can't stop that action .
How can I stop even all actions in my `CCScene`?

Comment: You're only looking at children of the currently running scene, which would be one of the layers (scroller?). I think you need to go down deeper into the node hierarchy to get to your CCMenu. As far as I know, `getChildByTag:` only goes down to the immediate child, not children of children.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do as follows:

//1.  Assign a tag to your action eg:

```
id action = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:10.0f angle:90.0f];
[action setTag:1001];
```

Run action:

```
[menu runAction:action];
```

when you want to stop it call

```
[menu stopActionByTag: 1001];
```

Answer (score -1):

use menu name in place of ccmenu

ccmenu->stopAllAction();